# Does PetaPoco v5x supports .NET 3.5 ? (I don't care about Dynamic)

Tags: petapoco

I want to use PetaPoco latest version (5x) with .NET Framework 3.5.

I've read that it works if you write some tuple classes, but I really don't want to do that, I just want to Nuget it and go.

I wont be using any Dynamic functionality (I thought it requires .NET 4x)

Thanks